# spring, struts + hibernate project start

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, struts2

I have next configuration:

#### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="Product.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

#### Product.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="com.project.model">
  <class name="Product" table="PRODUCT">
    <id name="id" column="PRODUCT_ID">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" />
    <property name="description" />
    <property name="price" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

#### struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
  "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
  <package name="Struts2Spring4Hibernate4Demo" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="listProduct" class="com.project.controller.ListProductAction">
      <result name="success">/WEB-INF/views/productList.jsp</result>
    </action>

  </package>
</struts>
```

#### applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <bean id="productDao" class="com.project.dao.ProductDaoImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
      <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>

  <bean id="listProductActionBean" class="com.project.controller.ListProductAction">
    <property name="productDao" ref="productDao" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.h2.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
  </bean>

  <tx:annotation-driven />

  <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
  </bean>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.controller" />.
</beans>
```

#### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>Struts2Spring4Hibernate4XML</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>DispatcherFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.project.contoller</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>DispatcherFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

#### ProductDaoImpl.java:

```
package com.project.dao;


import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import com.project.model.Product;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {
  private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  public ProductDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public List<Product> list() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Product> listProduct = (List<Product>)
      sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Product.class)
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
        .list();
    return listProduct;
  }
}
```

#### ListProductAction.java:

```
package com.project.controller;

import com.project.dao.ProductDao;
import com.projectmodel.Product;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

import java.util.List;

public class ListProductAction extends ActionSupport {
  private ProductDao productDao;
  private List<Product> listProduct;

  public void setProductDao(ProductDao ProductDao) {
    this.productDao = ProductDao;
  }

  public String execute() {
    listProduct = productDao.list();
    return SUCCESS;
  }

  public List<Product> getListProduct() {
    return listProduct;
  }
}
```

and when I try to deploy my app through Tomcat 8 - it throws next exception:

```
WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.doClose Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:357)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:836)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4776)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5390)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Transport.java:199)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:567)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've looked up at similar questions, but nothing found.

**UPDATE**

I've deleted context scan from app context and now get NPE at:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.project.controller.ListProductAction.execute(ListProductAction.java:25)

here is code:

```
public String execute() {
    listProduct = productDao.list();
    return SUCCESS;
  }
```

as I've researched, sessionFactory is instantiated normally, but spring(as I understand) cannot make binding, so **productDao** is null at ListProductAction

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: This is a WARNING? Can you ignore it or what is the problem?

Comment: No, it's not a warning. It's what I see in server console and I can't visit app start page (and tomcat is not running it, though it should by settings). Also there is a very large stacktrace, but I added here only the root cause

Comment: @RomanC I've removed context scan, and now application starts, opens page and throws 500 error, caused by : java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.project.controller.ListProductAction.execute(ListProductAction.java:25)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Comment: Why Spring should make any binding if it's running Struts?

Comment: @RomanC I'm trying to use Spring as IoC container and Strutc as a controller. May be I'm doing smth wrong ?

Comment: I didn't think people still used Struts. If you are using Spring, I'd use Spring MVC.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst technical requirements are to use these technologies together (actually, it's struts2 )

Comment: That's unfortunate. It seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst that's a useless, personal and also misleading comment, since this is Struts2, not Struts, and they're completely different

Comment: @AndreaLigios JEE or Spring seem to be the industry standards.  I have not seen a non-legacy project that uses Struts or Struts 2, but that's just my experience.

Comment: @IsaiahvanderElst J2EE is definitely legacy, since J2EE is Java 1.4. From Java 1.5 on, it is called Java EE. And I use Java EE along with Struts2 with no problems. According to what I've read the last time I've looked (a couple of years ago), Spring MVC is very popular in the USA, while it is not *that* popular in the rest of the world. (continue->)

Comment: I use it sometimes, and I like it, it has something more and something less than Struts2, that I still prefer. Java EE standard MVC framework is JSF2, that I don't like that much. Note that Struts3 is close to be released, because 2015's Struts2 is quite different from 2008's Struts2. Struts3 will be 2015's Struts2 with something more... I guess all these technologies will be replaced soon by client side framworks, however.

Comment: Oh, you edited J2EE on your own, good ;)

Comment: @JisforJava How could you use Spring with Struts2 without integration?

Comment: I'm glad my question and comments made such discussion, but maybe you'll help me? :)

Comment: @RomanC I've added apache struts2-spring-plugin. Or I've something wrong ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios Personally I like a Tomcat/Guice/Jersey setup, but I don't see this often. I've never worked outside of the united states, but the general consistence seems to be that Struts 2 was not able to work its way into the industry as a standard. That's not to say that it's not good, it's just not used regularly.  A big selling point for using a framework is that everyone knows how to use it, and that's why Spring is so popular.

Comment: @JisforJava When did you do it, after my comment?

Comment: Just clean build refresh.

Comment: @RomanC I haven't changed anything except deleting context scan

Comment: @AleksandrM I've tried clean install and deleting all files from target and put - nothing helped.

Comment: @JisforJava Do you have components at this package?

Comment: @RomanC if you mean classes - yes, I have them (code is in the question with package structure), hibernate and struts configuration files are at src/main/resources folder and spring configuration files are in WEB-INF folder

Comment: @JisforJava No, The context scan has a base package. In the previous comment you said you were *deleting context scan*? What do you mean?

Comment: @RomanC I've deleted line from appContex.xml : <context:component-scan base-package="com.project.controller" />

Comment: @JisforJava You said you can instantiate a `sessionFactory`, but can you instantiate `productDao`?

Comment: @RomanC in debug mode I see how productDaoImpl bean is instantiated and sessionFactory is set to him, but in action in execute() method - productDao is null

Comment: @JisforJava Could you post a picture with the evidences.

Comment: @RomanC added screenshot

Comment: @JisforJava I don't see *how productDaoImpl bean is instantiated and sessionFactory is set to him*.

Comment: @RomanC code of ProductDaoImpl is in the question